# Стилизация кнопок в Android приложении

Tags: android, design

Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке задать стиль кнопке в Android приложении. Я хотел бы сделать кнопку, у которой есть верхний и нижний бордер, и которая при нажатии меняет цвет текста, а бордеры исчезают. Код для бордеров я честно скопировал на просторах интернета и частично дописал сам. К сожалению разметка работает не совсем правильно. При нажатии на кнопку цвет текста меняется, но бордеры не пропадают. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить. Особенно здорово будет, если кто-нибудь в двух словах расскажет, как это вообще работает. Ниже представлен мой код.

Кнопка:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"        
    android:text="Some button"       
    android:textColor="@drawable/ButtonTextColor"
    android:background="@drawable/Button" />
```

файл Button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <!-- обычное состояние кнопки/ Этот код скопирован в интернете, 
   и я не до конца понимаю, что он делает -->
  <item>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
          <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#f00" />
          <solid android:color="#223" />
          <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

  <!-- когда кнопка нажата. Бордеры должны пропасть, но не пропадают -->
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#ff0"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

ButtonTextColor.xml. С ним вроде бы всё ок, цвет кнопки при нажатии меняется:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff" />
  <item android:color="#f00" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переместите состояние `android:state_pressed="true"` наверх:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- когда кнопка нажата. Бордеры должны пропасть, но не пропадают -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- обычное состояние кнопки/ Этот код скопирован в интернете,
  и я не до конца понимаю, что он делает -->
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="-2dp"
                android:right="-2dp"
                android:top="1dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#f00" />
                    <solid android:color="#223" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="10dp"
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:right="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>


</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте два отдельных `drawable` c рамками и без. После сделайте `drawable` `selector` для `background` кнопки, как у вас сделано для цвета текста (ButtonTextColor), только вместо свойства `color` используйте `drawable`